# How to create PHP/JSP/ERB tags using XSLT?

Tags: php, xml, xslt, erb, cdata

I have a bunch of XML files which I use to generate HTML pages. Those pages ultimately get marked up (by hand) with some `<%= %>` tags and made into Ruby .erb templates.

Is there a way to generate the special tags `<?php ?>` or `<%= %>` directly during the XSL transform?

I've tried using a `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>` block, but then the output generates with `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead of `<` and `>`.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation and a complete example how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Is there a way to generate the special tags <?php ?> or <%= %> directly during the XSL transform?
```

`<?php ?>` is not a "special tag" -- this is of a standard node type in the XPath data model -- a **[processing instruction](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#section-Processing-Instruction-Nodes)**.

there is also an XSLT instruction to create a PI:

**[`<xsl:processing-instruction>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#section-Creating-Processing-Instructions)**

Finally, you can create text like "<%= %>" if you use the **text** *output* method:

```
<xsl:output method="text"/>
```

but in the *text* output method you loseany node -- you should enter every output character as text.

So, it is a little-bit more convenient to use the default *xml* output method and the (non-mandatory!) attribute `disable-output-escaping="yes"` if this is supported by your XSLT processor.

**Here is an example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:processing-instruction name="php"/>
   <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
     &lt;% Hello World! %>
   </xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**applying this transformation to any XML document (not used) produces**:

```
<?php?>
     <% Hello World! %>
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks, this does the trick! I'm using Javascript to transform with `ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")` and `ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` and it seems to support the `disable-output-escaping="yes"` directive. :)